ARM NEON: how to implement logic like `mm_mask_compress`?
A function named filter_range is designed to retain elements nums[i] for which filter[i] != 0 and eliminate all others. Its logic is as follows.
static size_t filter_range(int* nums, const uint8_t* filter, size_t size) {
    size_t result_offset = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (filter[i]) {
            *(nums + result_offset) = *(nums + i);
            result_offset++;
        }
    }
    return result_offset;
}

For AMD's AVX512, the _mm512_mask_compress_epi instruction can be conveniently utilized to achieve this functionality. For ARM NEON, is it possible to employ SIMD instructions to maximize the acceleration of this function?

Inspired by this article, we could get matches, each four bits of which represents a filter value. Then we could use matches &= (matches - 1) and __builtin_ctzll to iterate through bits, which referred to as Kernighan's algorithm.
However, this is still worse than AVX512 version by using _mm512_mask_compress_epi.

static size_t filter_range2(int* data, const uint8_t* filter, size_t size) {
    constexpr size_t data_type_size = sizeof(int);
    size_t start_offset = 0;
    size_t result_offset = 0;

#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || defined(__aarch64__)
    std::cout << "__ARM_NEON__" << std::endl;
    constexpr size_t kBatchNums = 128 / (8 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    while (start_offset + kBatchNums < size) {
        uint8x16_t vfilter = vld1q_u8(filter);
        const uint16x8_t non_zero_mask = vreinterpretq_u16_u8(vmvnq_u8(vceqzq_u8(vfilter)));
        const uint8x8_t res = vshrn_n_u16(non_zero_mask, 4);
        // Each matched byte denotes 4-bit 1 (`0b1111`)
        uint64_t matches = vget_lane_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u8(res), 0);

        if (matches == 0) {
            // skip
        } else if (matches == 0xffff'ffff'ffff'ffffull) {
            memmove(data + result_offset, data + start_offset, kBatchNums * data_type_size);
            result_offset += kBatchNums;
        } else {
            matches &= 0x8888'8888'8888'8888ull;
            for (; matches > 0; matches &= matches - 1) {
                uint32_t index = __builtin_ctzll(matches) >> 2;
                *(data + result_offset++) = *(data + start_offset + index);
            }
        }

        start_offset += kBatchNums;
        filter += kBatchNums;
    }
#endif

    for (auto i = start_offset; i < size; ++i) {
        if (filter[i]) {
            *(data + result_offset) = *(data + i);
            result_offset++;
        }
    }

    return result_offset;
}


Does the filter have to come in that form? I ask because if you had it packed into chunks of 4 bits, you could use that to look up a shuffle-vector based on those 4 packed booleans and then you can use TBL to shuffle the retained elements together. You can do that anyway but having the filter pre-packed makes it easier.

@harold Yes, it does. However, maybe we could simulate mm_movemask to get a 16-bit mask, and divide the mask into 4 4-bit part?

After we have a 4-bit mask, then do we need to get the shuffle index vector from a const uint8x16_t shuffle_vectors[16] = { /*init*/ }; by shuffle_vectors[mask] and apply vqtbl1q_u8?

Basically like that. Perhaps with mask = (*((uint32_t*)&filter[i]) * 0x08040201) >> 24? This also reverses the bits, so the shuffle_vectors need to be in a different order than you may expect, but that costs nothing at runtime, just sometime to keep in mind when init-ing that array.

which compiler are you using? certain older compilers tend to  generate some inefficient code at times, would it be possible to post a godbolt link with the code and flags? https://godbolt.org/
Some compilers(e.g. GCC < 14) don't inline memmove and for such small copies like this it's beneficial to do so.  It's better to replace the memmove with vldq/vstrq's manually for portability and performance here.

You could also do vtstq_u8 (vfilter, vfilter) instead of vmvnq_u8(vceqzq_u8(vfilter)) for checking if vfilter!=0, save an instruction

Not NEON, but if you have hardware with SVE/SVE2 you can use svcompress to do the equivalent of the AVX512 operation.
